# PyReadonlyArray2 to Vec<T>

Tags: numpy, rust, numpy-ndarray, rust-ndarray

I would like to convert a 2D Numpy array in Python to a Rust vector.
Specifically, the second dimension of the array is known.
That is, the array is in shape [VARIABLE, 1024] (with type double)
I would like to know how I could convert it to a Rust vector.
Specifically, Vec<[f64; 1024]>

I know that I should use rust-numpy to do this
And the first step should be converting it into PyReadonlyArray2
But I'm not sure what should I do next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ndarray` does not support constant dimensions, so you won't find support for converting into arrays (`nalgebra` does support them, but it looks like it doesn't have support for converting to `Vec`). So the first step will be to convert to `Vec<f64>`, and then transmute that into `Vec<[f64; 1024]>` (this can be done without unsafe code with a crate like [`bytemuck`](https://docs.rs/bytemuck)).

The first step can also be quite involved if we want to do it efficiently. It will be good if we can just allocate directly and copy the contents using `memcpy()`; however, we can only do that if the array is contiguous (i.e. not a view that is not contiguous), *and* it is in C layout, i.e. row-major layout, and not Fortran layout (column-major).

All in all:

```rust
const ARRAY_SIZE: usize = 1024;

fn numpy_to_vec(arr: &PyReadonlyArray2<'_ f64>) -> PyResult<Vec<[f64; ARRAY_SIZE]>> {
    if arr.shape()[1] != ARRAY_SIZE {
        return Err(PyTypeError::new_err(format!(
            "expected column size to be {ARRAY_SIZE}",
        )));
    }

    let data = if arr.is_c_contiguous() {
        arr.as_slice().unwrap().to_vec()
    } else {
        let mut data = Vec::with_capacity(arr.len());
        let arr = arr.as_array();
        for row in arr.axis_iter(Axis(0)) {
            match row.as_slice() {
                Some(row) => data.extend_from_slice(row),
                None => data.extend(row),
            }
        }
        data
    };

    Ok(bytemuck::allocation::cast_vec(data))
}
```

**Edit:** Turns out this can be done with `ndarray` methods without much trouble, and this is also faster in case of non-contiguous layout:

```rust
const ARRAY_SIZE: usize = 1024;

fn numpy_to_vec(arr: &PyReadonlyArray2<'_, f64>) -> PyResult<Vec<[f64; ARRAY_SIZE]>> {
    if arr.shape()[1] != ARRAY_SIZE {
        return Err(PyTypeError::new_err(format!(
            "expected column size to be {ARRAY_SIZE}",
        )));
    }

    let mut data = arr
        .as_array()
        .as_standard_layout()
        .into_owned()
        .into_raw_vec();

    // Guard against case in which capacity%ARRAY_SIZE!=0, in which `bytemuck::allocation::cast_vec()` will fail.
    data.shrink_to_fit();

    Ok(bytemuck::allocation::cast_vec(data))
}
```

Comment: @fuo55631 I edited with an even better version.

Comment: The updated version worked like a charm!
One minor comment is that the compiler complains that .as_array() should be put in an unsafe block.

Comment: @fuo55631 It does not, and you should not use unsafe for that. If `as_array()` requires unsafe, that means you don't have [`PyReadonlyArray2`](https://docs.rs/numpy/latest/numpy/borrow/type.PyReadonlyArray2.html) but [`PyArray2`](https://docs.rs/numpy/latest/numpy/array/type.PyArray2.html), and the fix is to get one: call [`readonly()`](https://docs.rs/numpy/latest/numpy/array/type.PyArray2.html#method.readonly).

Comment: Just an update, it is unsafe only if I change PyReadonlyArray2 to PyArray2.

Comment: Thank you very much! Calling readonly() did the trick!